# MVC 4 Forms Authentication not working with [Authorize]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication, authorize

I'm learning MVC4 right now, and I am following the Pro ASP NET MVC4 4th edition book to create a Sports Store project.

I have always developed in webforms, and I am trying to figure out how the forms authentication is working in MVC4.

Here is what I have achieved:

> Web.Config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"/>  </authentication>
```

> AccountController login Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (authProvider.Authenticate(model.UserName, model.Password))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Admin"));
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Incorrect username or password");
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

> Auth Provider:

```
public bool Authenticate(string username, string password) {
            bool result = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
            if (result)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
            }

            return result;

        }
```

I am setting the AuthCookie and now I would like to know, how to protect other controllers
and actions out of the AccountController

The application has a controller called AdminController, where you can edit products and the
product list in under the following {controller/action}

> Admin/Index

So, If I am not missunderstanding the theory, if the user is not logging in the AccountController they should not be able to call actions with [Authorize] tag
on declaration:

```
 public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private IProductRepository repository;


        public AdminController(IProductRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
        }

       [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(repository.Products);
        }
   }
```

The thing is I can call the Index action of the Admin Controller without any problem and without introducing the login.

I need some guidance to understand how this works. I have done some research and could not find anything, and the book is not covering this topic.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT: I closed Chrome Browser and worked without changing anything. I was working with tabs and I guess the cookie was active even stopping and starting debugging.**

Comment: what Visual Studio version are you using? 2010 or 2012?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If a controller action is decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute (as is your `Admin/Index` action) you cannot invoke this action if you do not have a valid forms authentication cookie in the request.

Also in your `Login` action, upon successful authentication you should not return a view but you should redirect away, so that the cookie is properly set and available on subsequent requests.

Here's what should happen when a non-authenticated user attempts to access the protected `Admin/Index` action. The `[Authorize]` attribute will throw a 401 exception, which as you know from the classic WebForms will be intercepted by the Forms Authentication module and you will be redirected to the `loginUrl` configured in your web.config passing a ReturnUrl query string parameter the initially requested protected resource.

So you must have a `Login` action on the account controller that is not decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute and which should serve the view containing the sign-in view. The request will look like this:

```
/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fadmin%2Findex
```

Comment: Crap, I closed my browser and cleaned cache and now it is working without changing anything

Comment: Yes, maybe you had some forms authentication cookies left from a previous session.

Comment: You are the only one who helped and explained very nice. So accepted answer. Thank you very much

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - Can you please elaborate on this further: "Also in your Login action, upon successful authentication you should not return a view but you should redirect away, so that the cookie is properly set..."?  Why would returning a view and not redirecting away not set the auth cookie?